# How to simplify algebraic expression with exponents?

Tags: exponentiation

Can someone please tell me step-by-step how to simply this?

$$\sqrt{\frac{8x^{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}}$$

Edit: correct answer is 2x^(5/12), I'm just not sure how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{\frac{8x^{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}}=$$
$$\sqrt{\left(8x^{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)\cdot\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}=$$
$$\sqrt{8x^{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{2}{3}}}}\cdot\sqrt{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}=$$
$$2\sqrt{2}x^{\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^{\frac{2}{3}}}}\cdot\sqrt[4]{x}$$

Comment: Answer seems to be 2x^(5/12), I'm not sure how that simplifies.